# Possible bug in sorting question by votes

Tags: discussion, bug, questions

I was tried to sort answer by Votes and getting following error

> [image]

There should be question sorted by upvotes but i am getting error. what did i missed ?

Comment: This was reported on meta.SE, now to find it...